# How to run C++ test on visual studio online

Tags: unit-testing, azure-devops

I have test cases that are executable (*.exe files). There is no user interface involved. 
How do I use Team center /visual studio online to run these test cases on server.

For now, either on demand running or scheduled running will work for me.
(Currently I have no test case that runs on server. So you may mention the basic setup. )

I have written some test cases (they are exe files). I can run them locally line any other exe file.
My code is in C++.
My test cases are in C++.

Answer (score 0):

You could run them as part of your build. Just configure a build in VSO for your solution, and then modify the msbuild project file to call your tests and send the output to the build folder so it gets uploaded as part of the drop. If you are using VS, you would get a better experience using the VS unit testing support (i.e., get results in VS): http://www.visualstudio.com/get-started/run-tests-with-builds-vs.

Comment: Thanks. I am using VSO.